# pagify.js is adding my index page content to other pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, single-page-application

I'm currently using [pagify.js](https://github.com/cmpolis/Pagify) to create a simple one page site with jQuery.

I've followed the steps and called pagify on the container page *(index.html)* -

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#page_holder').pagify({
      pages: ['about', 'directory', 'archive','contribute'],
      animation: 'fadeIn', 
      'default': '',
      cache: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

and

```
<div id='container'>
    <header>
      <nav class="nav">
        <a class="column c1" href='#about'>About</a>
        <a class="column c1" href='#directory'>Directory</a>
        <a class="column c1" href='#archive'>Archive</a>
        <a class="column c1" href='#contribute'>Contribute</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
  <div id='page_holder' />
</div>
```

**The problem -**

When I add more html to the container page *(index.html)* it is shown on the four other pages of the site, although I only want it to be displayed on the index.html for obvious reasons.

To elaborate, I intend to display the below content **only** on my index.html, however when I add it to the page like so... -

```
      <div id='container'>
    <header>
      <nav class="nav">
        <a class="column c1" href='#about'>About</a>
        <a class="column c1" href='#directory'>Directory</a>
        <a class="column c1" href='#archive'>Archive</a>
        <a class="column c1" href='#contribute'>Contribute</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
  <div id='page_holder' />
    </div>


 </div>
   <div id="feed" class="feed" style="margin-top: 54px;">
    <div class="column c2">
            <p>
                Creatives of Colour (C-oC) is an independent directory
                that provides you with up to date information on
                current, and future work of creatives of colour
                being showcased in the UK. C-oC aims to contribute to the
                necessary exaltation of talented artists within the various
                ethnic minorities within the UK.
            </p>
            <p><a href="#">Find out more about Creatives of Colour..</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="column c3">             
        <span class="f-artist">Featured Artist</span>
            <br>
            <br>
                <div class="item-title">
                    <a href="#">Titles goes here</a>
                </div>
                    <div class="item-content">
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
                            do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
                            laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute 
                            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum 
                            dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                        </p>
                    </div>
    </div>
```

....it is also displayed on the about, directory, archive & contribute pages.

I hope this makes sense.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that's possible with pagify, as the whole point of a single-page-application is to create a framework like that. You might benefit from using a back-end language, where you'll be able to have partials and includes to denote sections of other page you'd like to include. Otherwise, you'll probably have to use JavaScript conditionals to denote which pages should display which additional content using `$.load()` or similar.

Comment: Ah I thought so. Currently thinking of just making my about page the same as the default page, not ideal but cant work. With `$.load()` would I just hide content on the specified pages?

Comment: Not sure on the **exact** structure you're going for, but you can load multiple 'segments' with `$.load()`, yes. Simply divide up your content in a way where the stuff you only want to display on some pages is in an independent file, and then `$.load()` that based on the URL :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Wow thanks it was really easy using '$.load()', thanks a lot for the help. Answer the question so I can accept it as the correct answer, if you like! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's it's possible to have different segments displayed on individual pages with `pagify.js`, as the whole point of a single-page-application is to create a framework which pages utilise.

You might benefit from using a back-end language like C#, where you'll be able to use **[using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)**, and have **[partials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods)**. Alternatively, PHP, has **[includes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)**. This way you can denote sections of other page you'd like to include.

As a JavaScript alternative, you can use JavaScript conditionals to denote which pages should display which additional content using jQuery's [**$.load()**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load multiple 'segments'. Simply divide up your content in a way where the stuff you only want to display on some pages is in an independent file, and then `$.load()` that based on the URL:

```
if (location.path.indexOf("index") > -1) {
  $("#container").load("content.html");
}
```

In the above example, the index page's `#container` is populated with the content from `content.html`.

Note that in a single-page-application which uses the structure `index.html#page`, you will need to target what follows the **hashtag** instead. To target the homepage (which is just `index.html`), you can check for the **lack** of a hashtag with:

```
if(!window.location.hash) {
  $("#container").load("content.html");
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: just noticed that when I refresh any of the pages on my site, they display the content that I've loaded explicitly on my index.html. This is strange, '<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#page_holder" ).load( "indexcontent.html" );
      });
    </script>'

Comment: Because you're trying to load the content in `#pageholder`, and I'm assuming that exists on every page. Depending on your structure, you may need to target an element that only exists on the index page. Having said that, you're not running any check that you're on the index. Check that you're on the index page with `if (location.path.indexOf("index") > -1)`, which ensures that the script will only run on URLs that contain the word `index`.

Comment: I'm loading content from a page called 'indexcontent' and I've checked that I'm on the index page with 'if (location.path.indexOf("index") > -1)' and now nothing show's on the index page.

Comment: Just realised that it's showing on every page because with pagify.js a new page still has 'index' in url...for example about page = index.html#about and directory page = index.html#directory...maybe its impossible to achieve with pagify.

Comment: In that case just check what's appended after the hashtag. You could just call the index `index.html#homepage`, and target `location.path.indexOf("homepage")`.

Comment: makes sense, but how can I call the index 'index.html#homepage'? This may be a silly question

Comment: You can always target the index directly with `if(!window.location.hash)`. That will trigger whenever there isn't a hashtag present.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148834/discussion-between-jordan-miguel-and-obsidian-age).